# Google Play developer console: beta test paid apps for free?

Tags: android, google-play

I've uploaded an apk as a beta version (beta testing section) in Google Play developer console and I'd like to let my users to test it. Final version will be paid and you can't change this choice after testing so I had to set it as paid at the beginning. The problem is I don't want to charge my users for testing and it seems there is no way to do so. Is there?

Comment: Consider a free app and use in-app purchase to let users unlock features. Or, you might want to consider a free and paid version and let the free users beta test the features you'll put into your paid version. With Gradle, it is easy to build the APKs simultaneously using flavors.

Comment: The curiosity is: Even if a registered Beta-tester buys the app , he get's the pubilshed apk from the play store instead of the beta apk (with newer version code). This behavior happens at least if you use google groups for beta-tester registration. If someone managed Paid-App + free Beta-testing within one package name , any hints would be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

I guess the usual pattern is to create 2 apps, 1 for "beta" and another one paid. 
Then you can set up a trial period for the beta, and if you need - extend the trial period with every update or so.

Well I think there more are options for this.

Comment: Ok, but I could do that even before Google's beta testing feature has been released. Your answer is good but has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to charge them and then refund the fee.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me how this solves the problem. Admittedly it is a workaround but there doesnt seem to be another way around it

Comment: Doesn't refunding remove their license from Google Play so that they won't be able to download updates any more?

Comment: No it does not actually.  This is a virtually undocumented "feature".  More info here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32635017/650322