# Android app, Give beta testers access to pro version for free

Tags: android, google-play

I have a free android app, and I will be adding a bunch of new features that will require unlocking by purchasing a pro package (seperate apk). However, I need to test these new features, and I want to offer my beta testers the pro package for free (as a reward/incentive for testing). Is it as simple as just sending them the pro apk to install over dropbox? Or would this pose a security risk for allowing my pro version to be installed on a device where it wasn't purchased through play store?

How exactly can I go about handing out free access to the pro package?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the android play beta testing features:

With test purchases using an in-app billing sandbox, you can let authorized users buy in-app products and subscriptions while an app is unpublished, without adding actual charges to the user accounts.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can use separate key store for signing the beta testing apk. When you plan to upload a production version on store, sign that apk with a separate release key store. Hope that simplifies your situation.

Comment: This sounds like it should work if I understand it right... So I can sign the incentive pro package with a different keystore than the one I upload to play store, and it should be okay?

Answer (score 0):

If you release a free apk then you risk having this apk distributed beyond your test group.

As an aside, it is also a good idea to verify the deployment method of any paid app to verify it was installed via authorized channels, which eliminates side-loading and greatly secures your app.

As for rewarding the testers you can do so by initiated a refund *yourself*.  It is an undocumented "feature" that developer-initiated refund do NOT revoke the license for an app.  They would need to pay, then you would refund them.  More info here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32635017/650322