# How to download app if you are a developer Android

Tags: android

I posted an app into google play production section and now I want to download it for testing. It's not free. I don't want to buy it. How can I do that?

Comment: i guess adding your google play app logged in gmail id as a test id in Google Play Developer Console will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

- Uninstall your current app on your device
- Go to play store and search your app
- If you were an alpha or beta tester, renounce to it
- Install your app again

Comment: I see just BUY botton with price on it. When I proceed, it want's me to enter my VISA card password.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way is to have two applications, one for testing and one in release. It is really a mess because package name must be unique within the market...

But it is the only way I can imagine right now. Release one only for alpha/beta restricted users (you) and publish as paid one when done.

I´ve read also here [How do I allow android app alpha/beta testers to download the app for free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227301/how-do-i-allow-android-app-alpha-beta-testers-to-download-the-app-for-free)

and here [Google Play developer console: beta test paid apps for free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605780/google-play-developer-console-beta-test-paid-apps-for-free)